# Error running EventDemo on Raspberry Pi with C

Tags: kaa

I'm trying to run EventDemo in C language on my Raspberry Pi, I already tried with C++ and got similar errors.

```
Event demo started
2016/11/08 9:04:37 [FATAL] [kaa_bootstrap_manager.c:403] (-3) - Error: No bootstrap servers's been found. Please regenerate SDK.
2016/11/08 9:04:37 [WARNING] [kaa_channel_manager.c:260] (-6) - Could not find access point for Bootstrap channel [0x98DA155C] (protocol: id=0x56C8FF92, version=1)
2016/11/08 9:04:37 [WARNING] [posix_kaa_client.c:394] (-8) - Failed to initialize channel, type 0
```

I follow the tutorial on how to compile Raspberry Pi for c/C++.
I'm running Kaa 0.9 on Sandbox, I already tested with one application in Java on my host machine and runs Kaa without problems.